# Multi-Level Table with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to replicate 3 tables on a page that draws information from the same array but using ng-repeat as a filter. I essentially used the same format of table from another thread. I have a JS fiddle Link herehttp://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/104/. The problem that I have is that similar to this jsfiddle thread, opening one table row opens all the table rows with the same index. The goal is to have the tables so that each table can only open one row at a time. Please help if possible.

Comment: It seems to work for me, only one row, can you please highlight the problem?

Comment: My apoligies, that was the incorrect link. http://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/104/. The issue that I am having is that when I click open the row on one table, the row on the other table is expanded as well. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your table into a directive and pass the data and the state as parameters

Like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/22874g90/) fiddle, the state of the first two tables are linked but the third one is independent:

```
    <my-directive table-state='table1State' store-data-model='storeDataModel'></my-directive>
    <my-directive table-state='table1State' store-data-model='storeDataModel'></my-directive>
    <my-directive table-state='table2State' store-data-model='storeDataModel'></my-directive>
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I needed, just as an extra note, is it possible to inject a template url into the directive if I had more than one type of table?

Comment: I would just extract the contoller and create another directive for the other html
http://jsfiddle.net/22874g90/1/